# Warehouse management using Excel and C#

Tags: c#, excel, search

I need basic idea on warehouse management using Excel and C#.

Actually, the warehouse file consist of 30 columns and 40,000 above record.

1. I need to select only select columns (suppose-12) from the uploaded Excel file (`.XLSX`)
2. I need to display 40,000 rows of data (all) with customized columns
3. Provide user auto search text-boxes (suppose for 5 columns-like truck no, order no, orderdate, wh-name) and display the search result at grid view
4. Edit and update the data searched by auto search (any row or implement update for all rows)
5. finally save the data into a new Excel or PDF file

Please help to implement these, using C# and Excel.

I tried but it takes 7-10 mins to save data from datagrid to new Excel file. I have problem with dynamic auto search columns

Comment: In the name of all that's holy, do NOT use Excel as a database. Or am I misunderstanding (please say yes) and you are using a real database  and jut wast to export to Excel...

Answer (score 1):

As a Suggestion: use http://epplus.codeplex.com/ to read the incoming file. Then put all the incoming material in some DataTables.
These DataTables could be used to implement the other functions way easier, since they are build to support that kind of actions.
Save any modified data to these Datatables.
Export them to a new xlsx file, that you can hand back. Agian, you can use epplus

Comment: 10 Minutes for saving with epplus?
That seems a bit over the top. May you used Excel Interop`?
If its true the problem is your way to big excel file...sorry, but Excel was never intended to easily accomodate 40.000 rows.
Switch to a database, it is easier in the long run.